# Ray - Triangle Intersection VS Ray - Parallelogram Intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

When trying to find the intersection of a ray and a parallelogram,
[in Derek Elkins left SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461034/raytracing-a-parallelogram-ray-parallelogram-intersection) he states you can simply do 2 ray triangle intersections

Where he is explaining how to do a ray parallelogram intersection he specifies if,

- $t>0$
- $0\leq\alpha\leq1$
- $0\leq\beta\leq1$

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in that range aren't you already solving for the parallelogram intersection so the statement about doing "2 ray - triangle intersections" is irrelevant as his method already applies to a parallelogram?

This now begs the question **what would the range of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be if you are trying to find a ray - triangle intersection?** My intuition tells me the range would be
$$0\leq\alpha+\beta\leq1,\alpha\geq0,\beta\geq0$$

Comment: You are correct

Comment: @TomKern thank you so much for the verification